# Webpack Code Splitting / Lazy Loading: Two files generated for one dynamic import() of an npm package

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I have an Angular 12 app which I bundle with Webpack 5 and I'm facing some problems implementing Webpack Code Splitting / Lazy Loading.

In my package.json I have the following dependency:

`"crypto-js": "4.1.1"`

So far, in my Angular code I have used:

`const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');`

When bundling with Webpack the ~200kb source code of crypto-js is included in my vendor.js. But this vendor.js now has grown so huge in size that I want to split my code and lazy load crypto-js (and others, but for now I just use crypto-js as an example). I only need that third-party library at a certain point in my app, so I started to use:

`import(/* webpackChunkName: 'crypto' */ 'crypto-js').then(CryptoJS => { ... });`

where I need it. Actually this works (the crypto-js is not in vendor.js anymore and it is lazy loaded where I need it), but with a very ugly behaviour: Webpack generates two files:
The file `crypto.js` (as defined with magic comment "webpackChunkName") and the file `480.js`. The file with the number contains the crypto-js source code and the `crypto.js` contains the following:

```
(self["webpackChunkclassroom"] = self["webpackChunkclassroom"] || []).push([[634],{

/***/ 42480:
/***/ (() => {

/* (ignored) */

/***/ })

}]);
```

When testing lazy loading both files are loaded from the server, that's why everything works. But instead of one request I have two, which is totally unnecessary and very ugly. In addition, I lose track of everything.

As a side mark:

When I copy the `crypto-js.js` from the node-modules folder to an assets folder in my web app and import this file:

`import(/* webpackChunkName: 'crypto' */ '../../assets/crypto-js.js').then(CryptoJS => { ... });`

then everything behaves exactly as I want. Only one file "crypto.js" is created and lazy loaded.

But I don't want to have JavaScript files in my assets folder (so that I have to keep them up-to-date by my own). I wanna use package.json and the benefits of NPM to keep my third-party libraries up-to-date.

Can somebody help me to solve my problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you could technically add it in an Angular module, so it gets bundled in there (and you can use node modules) and then lazy load that module, either by route or programmatically?

Comment: @MikeOne: How would I do that concretely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to make it work.

In the Webpack config I added the following `splitChunks` configuration:

```
   optimization: {
       splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                defaultVendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!crypto-js)/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

IMPORTANT:

- I exclude the NPM package `crypto-js` in the test regex
- The cachedGroup must be named `defaultVendors` (everything else will fail)